# Linear environment gradient

Tags: node-editor, vector-mapping, vector

How possible to make this environment gradient linear (not spherical like)
[image]

If I set location on X=0 gradient is no spherical, but I need it on bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use just the information for the Z (vertical) axis.

[image]

You can place the gradient where you need it by modifying the coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Read the question carefully, I nead transition on bottom, not a center

Comment: Easy, just move the coordinates where you need them. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I used window (not a object or generated) coordinate, as shown
[image]