# Creating a transparency mask using a texture and blending with shaders

Tags: transparency, masking

I want to give my ship's wings a kind of glitched holographic effect using a texture. I'm struggling with making a mask with a texture and making it so that the texture only affects,

1. The blue part of the wings
2. Only affects the edges.

I've tried just creating a simple gradient transparency using a color ramp with mapping+coordinates, but I think since the blue and white stars are separate shaders connected to a mix node with a color ramp controlling the factor it's not giving me the results I want. I'm not sure how to go about this though?

---

Here's how the wings look now and a concept of what I have in mind.

[image]

[image]

And here are my nodes

[image]

Comment: Use a gradient to control the mix of textures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45866/making-vertical-gradient-then-make-top-half-transparent and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199669/linear-environment-gradient/199814#199814

Answer (score 2):

I think I can point you in the right direction.

[image]

You need to define a wave texture and apply it along a gradient, so we'll need a wave texture node, and if you use a separate XYZ node you should be able to find a direction that gives you the gradient you need.  For this object it's the Z axis.

[image]

I'm going to use a Color Ramp to invert the Z gradient and give us a little more control if we choose to exercise it, a Math node to bump up the value, and then subtract out the wave texture.  I've clamped the last operation, but maybe it's not necessary.

[image]

If we use this map as the factor of a mix shader between the blue emission and a transparent BSDF, we can assemble the rest of your shader behind it and we get very close to your desired effect.

[image]

From here I think you can find something you like.  The way I chose to do this was to animate a 4d noise texture mixed into the coordinate space, and then move the minkowski voronoi texture along the Z axis.

[image]